# Does LoopbackJS automatically create createdAt and modified fields on a new model creation? How to enable?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm curious, does LB *automatically* create `createdAt` and `modified` fields on new model creation, like RoR does? LB docs says that it should, but when I try to create a new model, LB doesn't create those fields. Here is my script to create a new model and a new document in a MongoDB collection:

```
'use strict';

var server = require('./server');
var ds = server.dataSources.mongodb;
var collections = ['user'];


ds.automigrate(collections, function(er) {
    if (er) throw er;
    console.log('== Looback tables [' + collections + '] created in ', ds.adapter
        .name);

    server.models.user.create([{
        username: 'admin',
        password: "admin",
        email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    }], function(err, newUser) {
        if(err) {
            console.error("== Create ERROR ==:\n\r", err);
            ds.disconnect();
            process.exit(1);
        }
        console.log('== newUser ==:\n\r', newUser);
        ds.disconnect();
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

And this is the document created. No `createdAt` and `modified` fields:

```
 [ { username: 'admin',
    password: '$2a$10$.IqOjq1EEU1s1zEeb7IO7.tLAa0HljgS2frAR77AsoB8jgfZjWfi6',
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    id: 5642e5ecbf5d88742390971f } ]
```

How to enable that feature? Or should I explicitly pass those values every time I create a new model or modify an existing model? Like this:

```
server.models.user.create([{
    username: 'admin',
    password: "admin",
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    createdAt: new Date(), <--
    modified: new Date() <--
}]
```

Answer (score 8):

In your model definition file you can add createdAt property like this

```
   "createdAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "defaultFn": "now"
    }
```

This will add time stamp on every document creation. For modified property, there is no out of the box solution that I am aware of. One way to do this is to use [operation hook 'before save'](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-beforesave) to set timestamp on modified document.

Comment: Already there exist 'lastUpdated` property which can be used instead of `modified`. Also won't it be proper to make `lastUpdated`'s `"defaultFn": "now"` and make `createdAt` trigger only for remote method `create`?

Comment: @VishalKumar defaultFn: "now" will trigger only on create. If will set default value only if it is empty. Update will not change this.